# Get Value From Hash Based on String

Tags: ruby

I have a hash looks like :

```
response = {
  data: {
     target_file: "file.jpg"
  }
}
```

and have a string `"data.target_file"`

What I want is how can I access `target_file` value based on that string, like accessing with `response[:data][:target_file]`

how can I convert as dinamically from string `"data.target_file"` to `response[:data][:target_file]`

so I don't want use something like `response["#{string.split('.')[0]}".to_sym]["#{string.split('.')[1]}".to_sym]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split` like you've shown to convert the keys into a string array, then `map` the strings into symbols and finally `dig` the hash whilst extracting the array elements as arguments with the splat operator `*`:

```
response.dig(*"data.target_file".split(".").map(&:to_sym))
```

If you see yourself repeating this code, you can extend the `Hash` class and add a method that does it:

```
class Hash
  def dot(path)
    self.dig(*path.split(".").map(&:to_sym))
  end
end
```

Then you would simply use:

```
response.dot("data.target_file")
```

Comment: Ah I didn't relize about `dig` method in hash..

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig